# Why Does SciPy Optimize Curve Fit require x data to start at 0

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have written the code below to import data and fit a function to it. The code works fine, however a problem arises if I attempt to select a range of data that does not start with the first point x=0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


data = np.loadtxt('/home/alex/Downloads/Tuesday_trial1.txt');



x = [row[0] for row in data]
t = np.asarray(x)
y = [row[1] for row in data]


def sho(t,a,v,w,p,o):
    return a*np.exp(-v*t/2)*np.cos(w*t-p)-o

popt,pcov = curve_fit(sho,t,y)
```

When altering the data so that the first entry in the x column of data is 100 sec rather than 0 seconds this is the result (otherwise it is a perfect fit).

[fit curve with x data starting at 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJASC.png)

I have also tried to leave the data be and select the desired range through python via

```
x = [row[0] for row in data]
t = np.asarray(x[100:1500])
y = [row[1] for row in data]
y = np.asarray(y[100:1500])
```

Both methods result in the above image. Is there a way to fit this function to only a specific range of the data? What is going wrong in the code when the x data starts at a value other than 0?

Comment: Difficult to help without knowing your data; could you post them, too?!

Comment: Please post a link to the data.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is due to not providing an initial guess for the parameters.